# Manage statistics with drupal

Tags: nodes, log-messages

I have a site that get statistics on products. I get data from an external source to update the Drupal DB to register a buy on a product and the date of that buy to be able to show a flowchart over that product.

I need this statistics for showing the development of the products selling rate. So if one customer buys a product that information will be sent to my Drupal DB, and that's where I wonder how I should construct my DB so it is optimal in speed and storage. Is it a good idea to create a content type that has a product entity reference and a date? So when a product is bought a new node is created that holds the date and product as information.

Comment: I posted hold vote before additional data (second paragraph) was provided. Could you maybe provide some info why it's on hold now? I don't say it shouldn't, I just say OP deserves more detailed explanation I can't give him now. Especially when it got held almost 2 hours after defining problem and finding answer.

Comment: I was also wondering but I am new here so I was not sure about the rules. I can see how this is an unclear question. But as I got an answer from Mołot it seemed to clear up what the question was about (as I was not sure what to exactly ask Mołot helped me to define that). Should I still edit the question?

Comment: I nominated it for reopening. I don't think it will get reopened this time, but hopefully more experienced reviewers will be able to provide more detailed suggestions. Then edit your question - it will nominate for reopening again, and it should be good. Please don't feel down, this system is simply a quality assurance, and "But I know what I meant" happens to everyone.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation and encouragement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data should not be nodes, as they do not keep any readable content on their own, they only make sense in connection to a product and in statistics, summaries et cetera, and shouldn't really be displayed on their own. So, you have two ways of dealing with them:

1. Bad way - make them just a multi-value field in product content type. Not optimal for storage, not really good for filtering.
2. Make them entities. You only need creation date and product reference on them. Making them entities will expose them to Views for easy filtering and aggregation, to search api if you will ever need to sort by "most sold", and, well, to each and every module that knows about entities. There are many answers and tutorials out there. Hint - your entity should not be a fieldable one. Non-fieldable entities always have only fields defined at creation, so storage is much simpler for them. And simpler == faster.

Comment: Thanks! I will look up how to create my own entity and to fetch data from DB to my entities.